# react native accessibility Android

Tags: accessibility, react-native

I am trying to implement Accessibility in react native application(used Accessibility API). I have a Volume button in my app, with two states (Mute state and normal state). I need to update the AccessibilityLabel according to the state change.

```
accessibilityLabel={this.state.muted? 'Volume Button' : 'Volume Button muted'}
```

I have achieved this Accessibility label in iOS, in Android it is not working?What is the solution for this? Do I need to pass any events in Android?

Comment: I think accessibilityLabel should be a string.

Comment: Yes I have added it in String

Comment: Is it now working now?

Comment: No, It is working only in iOS, in Android not working

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. You should try another device.

Comment: I tried in 2 or 3 devices, but in Android it is not working

Comment: Did this ever get fixed? I can't get accessibility labels to work on android

Answer (score 0):

with those two props, the VoiceOver and TalkBack should work fine:

```
accessible={true}
accessibilityLabel={this.state.muted? 'Volume Button' : 'Volume Button muted'}
```